# Web application for database design colaboration

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there a web application that you can use for collaborative database design?

Something in the line of [SQL Designer](http://code.google.com/p/wwwsqldesigner/), but with the option of collaboration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used an application called http://www.dabbleboard.com/ - not a bad online app to try.  It's not specifically designed for database design but does help in building an ERD.

Answer (score -1):

Not quite sure if this is what you are looking for?  http://www.embarcadero.com/products/er-studio-repository